# Enzyme/Jest React Testing - Shallow connected component with react-redux > 6

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

We use Enzyme and Jest for testing.
Updated to the latest version of react-redux in our code base, and all of the connected component test cases started failing (Version 6).
Using

```
import { createMockStore } from 'redux-test-utils';
```

to create store

Test cases that worked with older version:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<SomeConnectedComponent />, {context: { store }});
```

This fails giving error

*Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(SomeConnectedComponent )".*

Reading few posts, got a suggestion to mount and wrap with provider wrapper

```
const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><SomeConnectedComponent /></Provider>);
```

Above code works, but I want it to work with swallow for unit testing.

Edit :

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}>
<SomeConnectedComponent />
</Provider>)
```

Above code returns empty shallowWraper object.

What is the best way to swallow connected component with react-redux version > 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shallow does not work with the latest version of react-redux. 
From Version 6.x, it causes the mentioned problem.

The best solution I found was to use a older version of react-redux for testing, 
and the newer one for actual code.

1) Add the older version as a dev dependency. Because a newer version of react-redux is there you will need to use a alias. This can be any version 5.x This will install "react-redux-test"

```
yarn add react-redux-test@npm:react-redux@5.0.6 -D
```

2) Under the _ mocks _ folder, create a new file react-redux.js and export the older version from within

```
export * from 'react-redux-test';
```

This mock will be used in every test case file by default, so the old testing code no longer breaks.

If however you want to test with the new react-redux library, you can use

```
jest.unmock('react-redux')
```

above the new test file.

After upgrading there were hundreds of tests failing, this approach works for me as i want to use the Hooks Api in new components as well.

This way you can use features the new library until enzyme / react-redux come up with a fix.

Comment: Got me on the right path. I had to do jest.mock('react-redux', () => {
  return require('react-redux-test');
}) in setupTests.js. For some reason it didn't work if it was under the __mocks__ folder.

Comment: seems like this version dont have the `useDispatch()` hook react-redux has in ver 8?

Answer (score 7):

shallow does work on redux 7 but the implementation changed. 
so instead of

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store <SomeConnectedComponent/></Provider>)
```

you now do

```
const wrapper = shallow(<SomeConnectedComponent store={store}/>)
```

Wrapping in a provider is no longer necessary and prevents unnecessary dives. You are then able to traverse the shallow wrapper like so:

```
wrapper.children().dive().find(<ChildComponent>))
```